# WPF Button Style Background hidding Foreground

Tags: wpf, templates, foreground

I'm trying to understand the basics of styling controls with templates but even though there are a lot of samples I'm still stuck with some basics.

I wish to style a button with a custom background, therefore I set a border with a background property changing on VisualState "MouseOver". The problem is, since I set the color on the border, I can't find find how to set my text foreground property to white so that the text is visible.

Here's my xaml:

> ```
>    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
>         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
>         <Setter Property="Template">
>             <Setter.Value>
>                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
>                     <Border Name="RootElement">
>                         <Border.Background>
>                             <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
>                                 <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black" />
>                                 <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="SteelBlue" />
>                             </LinearGradientBrush>
>                         </Border.Background>
>                         <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
>                             <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
>                                 <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
>                                 <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
>                                     <Storyboard>
>                                         <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
>                                             <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightSteelBlue" />
>                                         </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
>                                     </Storyboard>
>                                 </VisualState>
>                             </VisualStateGroup>
>                         </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
>                     </Border>
>                 </ControlTemplate>
>             </Setter.Value>
>         </Setter>
>     </Style>
> ```

The setter on Foreground property seems to be overriden by the border background property.

I think I have to add a textblock to the template, but I'm sure how to link the actual Text of the button to the textBlock, this is what I tried without succes:

> ```
>     <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
>         <Setter Property="Template">
>             <Setter.Value>
>                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
>                     <Border Name="RootElement">
>                         <Border.Background>
>                             <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
>                                 <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black" />
>                                 <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="SteelBlue" />
>                             </LinearGradientBrush>
>                         </Border.Background>
>                         <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
>                             <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
>                                 <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
>                                 <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
>                                     <Storyboard>
>                                         <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
>                                             <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightSteelBlue" />
>                                         </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
>                                     </Storyboard>
>                                 </VisualState>
>                             </VisualStateGroup>
>                         </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
>                         <TextBlock Name="ButtonText" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}">
>                             <TextBlock.Foreground>
>                                 <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
>                             </TextBlock.Foreground>
>                         </TextBlock>
>                     </Border>
>                 </ControlTemplate>
>             </Setter.Value>
>         </Setter>
>     </Style>
> ```

Comment: I just tried your second style and it looks right to me, I get a very nice black to blue background colour and white text on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you need to add something to present the text in the Button, a simple ContentPrsenter inside the border should do.

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="RootElement">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="SteelBlue" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightSteelBlue" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <ContentPresenter/>

                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

If you want more control over what displays the content you could add something like a Label and bind to the Content property of the button.

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="RootElement">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="SteelBlue" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightSteelBlue" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply, this solved my problem. How can it be that the "TemplateBinding Content" is actually working with a label but not with a textblock ?

Comment: Well actually it did for TextBlock too as long as there is a string in there, the Type of the buttons Content property is Object I think.

Comment: Late I know but why is the border background styled and not the button background?